# wrong result regexp

Tags: php, regex

Here is my string:

```
/index.php?option=com_podstrony&id=1
```

and I want to get from it "com_podstrony"

here is my regexp: `/^\/*index.php\?option=(.*)+&.*$/`
but result is wrong:

```
option=com_podstrony&id=1
```

I'm using PHP `preg_replace`.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `I'm using PHP preg_replace`: Can you post the code you are using? Why are you using preg_replace instead of preg_match?

Comment: Nice tool to test your Regular Expressions at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ also do not forget accept answer if it solve your problem (since your accept rating pretty low)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use a regex...

```
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $get);

echo get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($get['option']) : $get['option'];
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/lKboLYUZ).

But if you wanted to use a regex for some reason...

```
preg_match('/^\/index\.php\?option=(?P<option>[^&;]+).*$/', $url, $matches);

echo $matches['option'];
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yjCXG0).

Comment: You may want to consider magic_quotes_gpc setting. Quote: *The magic_quotes_gpc setting affects the output of this function, as parse_str() uses the same mechanism that PHP uses to populate the $_GET, $_POST, etc. variables.*

Comment: Alex's second method works great! But I can't figire out what the semicolon ";" do in this part of expression "[^&;]+". Can u help me?

Comment: @MariuszPaleo It is just because a semi-colon is a valid GET param delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

First, what about this regexp?

```
@^/*index.php\?option=(.+)\&.@
```

I removed "end of line" and replaced `/` delimiter with `@`

Second, are you sure you need to parse URL with regexp like that? Common practice is parse only `index.php` part and leave rest to your webapp (`$_GET` parameters).

Comment: That would match a string such as `////index+php?option=hello&a`.

Comment: @alex You're right! I forgot to escape `.` and some other stuff. "Stupid copypaste", as we call it at my workplace :-)